# How to set up persistent object for one-to-many and many-to-many at same time? [DevExpress]

Tags: c#, linq, devexpress, xpo

I have an issue with  next scheme, I attached it.I want to query from my database with only one object with "`Manufacturer`" class. Like:

```
var res = new XPQuery<Manufacturer>(session);
```

And then query all info that are related to my condition in LINQ.
I have tried `XPLiteObject, XPObject, Association attribute, NoForeignKey Attribute, XPOCollection` and a lot of stuff but nothing didn't help me.

I have tried a lot of approaches and every time I have new exception like:
SelectMany - method is not supported.
Can't set foreign key in table.
Duplicate primary key.

My question is: how to describe classes for normal extraction data from db?
[image: TableScheme]

UPD:
My solution now is: to use .ToList() at every object
and then use linq-query for join data and make needed query.

```
var manufacturer = new XPQuery<Manufacturer>(session).ToList();
var cars = new XPQuery<Car>(session).ToList();
var countries = new XPQuery<Country>(session).ToList();

var result = from m in manufacturer ....
```

Comment: I think you want to "Include" your referenced properties, right? Meaning having a "drilldown" from 1 object to others?

Comment: @Dimitri, yes, you are right. I added my solution into question, you can look at it.

Comment: I have no experience at all with DevExpress but have a look at this=> https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112681/Task-Based-Help/Filtering/How-to-Implement-Cascading-Filtering-for-Lookup-List-Views OR https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113637/Getting-Started/Comprehensive-Tutorial-MainDemo-Application/Business-Model-Design/Business-Model-Design-with-Entity-Framework/Implement-Dependent-Reference-Properties-EF and see if that can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found a solution to my question.
I downloaded [DevExpress](https://documentation.devexpress.com/GeneralInformation/15033/Installation/Download-the-NET-Products-Installer) that can add templates for visual studio.
Then I select Add new item to my project named "*DevExpress ORM DataModel Wizard*".
This wizard [can create persistent objects for existing database](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/3334/concepts/generating-persistent-objects-for-existing-data-tables).
After that I can query database with next syntax:

```
var manufacturer = new XPQuery<Manufacturer>(session).Select(x => x....)...;
```

But if you want to use *.SelectMany()* in your LINQ query you should use *.ToList()* and then use *.SelectMany()*. I faced with a lot of issues when I have tried to join or perform some other LINQ related operations. Well, if you got some errors, firstly after *.Select()* try .*ToList()* and then perform your operation.